# Arabic alphabets and spaces check function

Tags: javascript, html

I have this JavaScript function which allows me to input only Arabic characters and discard any other characters, numbers and spaces.

Whenever I enter a string like `السلام عليكم` it discards the space and changes it to `السلامعليكم`

So how can I make it accept the white space between the words.

```js
function CheckArabicOnly(field) {
  var sNewVal = "";
  var sFieldVal = field.value;

  for (var i = 0; i < sFieldVal.length; i++) {

    var ch = sFieldVal.charAt(i);;
    var c = ch.charCodeAt(0);

    if (c < 1536 || c > 1791) {
      // Discard
    } else {
      sNewVal += ch;
    }
  }

  field.value = sNewVal;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="department_name" value="" size='18' id="txtArabic" onchange="CheckArabicOnly(this);" required>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Find the charCode for spaces and don't discard them. It's easy.

Comment: [It's `32`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)

Comment: I've tried to exclude the space chaCode which is 32 from the if statement but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You could add the space char code (`32`) as exception in your condition like:

```
if ((c < 1536 || c > 1791) && c != 32) {
```

```js
function CheckArabicOnly(field) {
  var sNewVal = "";
  var sFieldVal = field.value;

  for (var i = 0; i < sFieldVal.length; i++) {
    var ch = sFieldVal.charAt(i);;
    var c = ch.charCodeAt(0);

    if ((c < 1536 || c > 1791) && c != 32) {
      // Discard
    } else {
      sNewVal += ch;
    }
  }

  field.value = sNewVal;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="department_name" value="" size='18' id="txtArabic" onchange="CheckArabicOnly(this);" required>
```

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't work, whenever I click on other textbox the space between words is discarded

Comment: It seem like you've a cache problem, the snippet works just fine , try to Ctrl+F5 to clear the cache in your browser or try the code in private navigation...